# Alien as Date for Hire, Can Change Appearance

Tags: story-identification

I read a short story, I think it was by a female author, for a sci-fi class. The alien in the story is part of a race that's living peacefully on Earth. They are subjugated though.

I remember a scene where one of the aliens is stuck on a piece of rock or something in a park and some human teens are taunting it and the stuck alien is desperate for a drug or food that the humans have. Ring any bells? I think the aliens might have been blue but I'm not 100% on that.

Comment: Can you provide any more information, such as when you read the story or what time period it was set in? How does the information in the title fit with the rest of the description?